# Dropdownlist mvc: how to set a value and save in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working on the MVC Dropdownlist for the first time. I am able to populate the dropdownlist values from the database, but my problem is with the save functionality, on httppost in the controller, the selected value needs to save in the database and I am currently stuck at this point. Here's my view and the controller code:

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DisplayNumber, new SelectList(Model.DropdownQuestions.Where(m => m.question_part_number == 0), "DisplayNumber", "ValueDescription", 1, "---Select One---"))

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(HsipDropdownQuestionsViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {

            string cRegion = "00";
            string cStateCode = "05";
            short nFY = 2016;
            decimal reportId = 1;
            decimal sectionId = 1;
            decimal subsectionId = 1;
            decimal questionNumber = 16;
            decimal questionPartNumber = 0;
            decimal displayNumber = 21;
            decimal colNumber = 1;
            string userId = string.Empty;



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                decimal? rowNumber = model.DisplayNumber;
                model.ValDescription = model.DropdownQuestions.First(p => p.DisplayNumber == model.DisplayNumber).ValueDescription;
                string response = model.ValDescription;


                hsipdropdownRepository.SaveDropdownValues(cRegion, cStateCode, nFY, reportId, sectionId, subsectionId, displayNumber, questionNumber, questionPartNumber, rowNumber, colNumber, userId, response);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "DropdownQuestions");
            }

            return Content("saved");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

the issue here is the Save response method is coming from the stored proc result. 
Here the value description and display number needs to get populated with id value and the dropdownlist selected value so that it can save it to the database. I am not sure why it cannot get the values from the model.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: What are you not getting specifically ? `model.DropdownQuestions` will not be posted back. You need to to query that again in your HttpPost action if needed.

Comment: You will not get values on Controller With `DropDownList` change it to `DropDownListFor`

Comment: Can you please provide whole view page?

Comment: @Ghanshyam: That is the relevant part of the view I have and I am using dropdownlistfor

Comment: Did you debug the `model` parameter, what did you see inside the `model.DropdownQuestions`? I guess there should be only selected option  inside it instead the whole options of select

Comment: All you have is a `DropDownListFor()` method that binds the value of the selected option to property `DisplayNumber`. The `foreach (var m in model.DropdownQuestions)` code in your POST method makes no sense - you do not and should not be generating form controls for each property of each item in your `DropdownQuestions` collection

Comment: Hi Steven my updated controller post action looks like above. I have updated my original post.

Comment: @Hari, Did you not understand my comment. `model.ValDescription = model.DropdownQuestions.....` will throw an exception because the value of `DropdownQuestions` is `null`! No idea why you need the value of `ValDescription` since its never used, but you need to get it by querying the database based on the value of `DisplayNumber`. And why in the world do your have `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValDescription)` when you do not even have a form control for it